# tensorflow: build a dataset with duplicated images?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I'm using tensorflow to detect if an box is empty or not. 
There can be a variety of things in the box, there is no need to detect the content (if the box is not empty).
The box, placement, and lightning is always the same.

my dataset has 2 labels: empty, notEmpty.
now my label 'empty' contains images that are 99% equal to each other, because every empty scenario looks the same.

I'm trying to improve my dataset and have the following questions:

- does it matter that the images for 'empty' are (almost) identical?
- can duplicating the same picture improve my model? (my dataset wil get bigger and 'notEmpty' won't contain duplicates)
- is there some technique for this problem/situation?

I hope anyone can help me get answers for these questions.
If you have sources how to improve an image dataset please let me know.

Comment: Checking if a box is empty or not is a simple image classification task. You can use techniques like [thresholding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03217) to classify the images.

Comment: You are right, however this software is used in multiple usecases, so I prefer to keep using tensorflow + keras, and make it also accurate for this specific case. (there is reflection in the empty box, so not sure if tresholding will work)

Comment: "data augmentation" is an approach applicable especially for image processing. You flip, adjust contrast, adjust brightness, crop etc.,  and by doing this generate additional training examples. You can do this with your own code or use the support of tensorflow, for example https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator?version=stable